# COM library not creatable on SQL Server 2014 COM

Tags: sql-server, com, activex, sql-server-2014

We are running SQL Server 2014 64 bit on Windows Server 2012 64 bit and having troubles with an old COM library written in VB6.

`sp_OACreate` is returning null with no error.

The COM library is registered and located on the server itself and it can be successfully invoked by a test program executed from the server desktop using the SQL account or other account.

Other COM objects such as "`Scripting.FileSystemObject`" can be created and destroyed in SQL using the same login or other logins. Only our custom COM library is failing.

Would this be a permissions issue at the server or database level or could it be something else? We use this same COM library on many other SQL Server.

Comment: Begin made in VB6, the component is definitely 32-bit. If this is an in-process component, a 64-bit process, like SQL Server 2014, can't load it.

Comment: You can't load a 32 bit in-proc server in a 64-bit application. If your COM object is well behaved it may work running as a DLL surrogate. See: http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component being a VB6 creation it was required to register it to run out of process.